# How do I calculate the number of values on each XML tag with python?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, elementtree

I am trying to calculate the numbers of values of a particular tag. I am absolutely new to this. Here is what I have tried:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et 

tree = et.ElementTree(file='cars.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root:
    print(len(child))
```

However, this technique does not allow me to know how many cars each make has. 
e.g: BMW: 14;

Comment: Please show us what cars.xml looks like.

Comment: I am totally I am have problem with writing codes in here: how do i put that that in the grey box.? Your codes works but its only counting the main tags : I have 8 length of the file . but I need to count each  make. I also have  Mercedes, Ford, Audi, Jaguar, Toyota, Peugeot and Nissan.

Comment: I am totally I am have problem with writing codes in here: how do i put that that in the grey box.? Your codes works but its only counting the main tags : I have 8 length of the file . but I need to count each  make. I also have  Mercedes, Ford, Audi, Jaguar, Toyota, Peugeot and Nissan. How can I loop to see each tags and values their contain?? thanks a lot  mzjn

Comment: Here is how you add code and preformatted text: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code